# Why can't I see my troops in my coc game?

Tags: clash-of-clans

My barracks show that they are full but I don't see any troops in my army camp and I can't see my barb king. You can see his energy level near the right mortar. And you can see that there are no archers on my archer towers. And no wizard on my wizard towers.

[image]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of this? Does this happen even in attacks? Have you tried to reinstall the game so the bug goes off?

Comment: Yes it does happen while attacking.

Comment: I'll try reinstalling.

Comment: Don't forget to backup your game!

Comment: Yeah this happened with me, I reinstalled the game! It worked fine then.

Answer (score 2):

This is caused by a cache error in the game. Usually re-opening the game fixes it, but if not go to Settings > Applications > Application Manager > Clash of Clans > Storage > Clear Cache. This works for Android devices, so if you use an Apple device just navigate to the application in your settings.

If you can't clear the cache/are unable to just restart your phone (or if it doesn't work), re-install the app.

Answer (score 0):

Clear data by going into application manager for the app(Clash of Clans) and launch the app again. It will definitely work!

Answer (score -2):

Clearing the cache works better than deleting the data.

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem and forcing it to stop and clear the cache fix it for me on an Android. Better than reinstalling :)